# What Charts Library is ICONOSQUARE using?

Tags: chart-design

I am currently using HighCharts but I think it is not as elegant as the ones ICONOSQUARE is using.

Does anyone know what Charting Library are they using?

Also if anyone has a good list of well designed and easy to use Chart Libraries I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of charting frameworks that can be found by searching the web. One of my favourites is http://www.chartjs.org, but there are many others, some of which are listed here: https://www.sitepoint.com/15-best-javascript-charting-libraries/ Which is the best is entirely subjective.

In terms of ICONOSQUARE, I doubt that they are using a library or framework that is publicly available. They are probably creating their own Javascript, CSS, etc. Which is why they can charge people to use it.